# Запятая перед "и вряд ли"

Tags: пунктуация

[image]

Меня интересует, почему тут стоит запятая перед "и вряд ли"? Тут ведь продолжение пояснения: потому что — преподаватель и вряд ли смогу выдержать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vladiko поражает своей грамотностью.   
Во-первых, перед *"что"* нужна запятая, так как вводное слово является поводом разделить союз *"потому что"*. Во-вторых, запятая перед *"и"* не нужна как минимум потому, что это СПП, а придаточные части, соединяющиеся союзами *"и", "да"(="и") "или"* и *"либо"*, не разделяются запятой. Но даже если бы предложение было бы ССП, то разделять его запятой не надо было бы, так как *"преподаватель русского языка"* и *"вряд ли смогу выдержать"* - однородные сказуемые.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение неполное, его можно восстановить следующим образом:
(Мы не с тобой), наверное, потому, что я преподаватель русского языка, и (поэтому я) вряд ли смогу такое выдержать.

Здесь возможно авторское решение: сложное предложение с подчинительной и сочинительной связью. (Последнее предложение можно представить как неполное). Сначала указывается причина (ответ на вопрос), а потом отдельным предложением указывается следствие.

Answer (score 0):

единственно разумное объяснение запятой- часть И ВРЯД ЛИ СМОГ ТАКОЕ ВЫДЕРЖАТЬ является придаточным следствия, которое зависит от предыдущего придаточного причины. Таким образом, получаем сложноподчиненное предложение с последовательным подчинением придаточных. Запятая нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Позвольте и мне внести свои 3 копейки в попытки оправдать коллегу - преподавателя русского языка. Думаю, единственный повод поставить запятую перед "и вряд ли..." - это понимание второй части ССП как присоединительной конструкции, которая начинается союзом "и" в присоединительном значении "и притом".  Действительно, главное высказывание прозвучало:"потому что я преподаватель русского языка". А затем следует добавочная мысль, дополнение: "и притом вряд ли смогу такое выдержать". Соглашусь с оппонентами: мое объяснение не очень убедительно, "притянуто за уши", так как присоединительное значение здесь еле-еле прощупывается.

Answer (score -2):

Запятые у Марики расставлены правильно.

Comment: Отрицательная оценка убрана. Скрин взят, насколько я знаю, из собрания в стиле "нарочно не придумаешь", так что снижать оценку тут не за что (если, конечно, у Вас есть чувство юмора).  
yupaz, Вас спросили ПОЧЕМУ стоит запятая, а не "правильно или нет". Читайте внимательно вопрос.

Comment: При постановке и непостановке зпт в данном предложении слегка изменяется его смысл. Если рассматривать части предложения как однородные члены с общим подлежащим (зпт не поставлена), то не читается зависимость второй части от первой. В данном же случае запятая подчеркивает, что она не сможет такое выдержать именно потому, что она преподаватель русского языка.